# Link new registration to existing database?

Tags: relational-database

I currently have an existing mySQL school database and want to enable parents to register their children to the school's program through the school website. The database has information of parents and students. The database keeps track of the relationships between parents and students. Currently, there is no account at all on the school website. I would like parents to register to the site, and after they register, they see a list of their children and their existing information. Then, parents can register their children to the school's program.

My question is how to link between parent's account registration on the website to the parent's entry of the database. My concern here is authentication because I don't want to disclose student information to the wrong person. How do I know the person that registers on the website is the actual parent? Are there any approach, mechanism or fields that are commonly used to resolve this issue?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

1) Send letters with preset passwords to the parents through trustworthy channels using the data in the school database: address (p-mail) or mobile phone number (SMS) or e-mail.

2) Let the parents (on the web side) prove theeir identity through their knowledge of the relevant data in the school database.